# Сериализация enum в json в виде строки

Tags: c#, json, json.net

У меня есть класс со свойством типа `enum` property и при сериализации в json оно выводится как число, в то время как мне надо чтобы результат был в виде строки.

В качестве примера:

```
enum Gender { Male, Female }

class Person
{
    int Age { get; set; }
    Gender Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Желаемый вариант json:

```
{ "Age": 35, "Gender": "Male" }
```

Каким способом это можно сделать?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [JavaScriptSerializer - JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2441290/5752652) от участника  [@Omer Bokhari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56829/omer-bokhari).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2441290

Answer (score 3):

Раз вы пользуетесь json.Net то можете просто использовать атрибут

```
class Person
{
    int Age { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    Gender Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Также можно указать при настройке сериализатора:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject, 
    new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
```

или:

```
serializer.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
```

Документация: [StringEnumConverter Class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm)

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [JavaScriptSerializer - JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2441379/5752652) от участника  [@Matt Dearing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277211/matt-dearing).</sub>